# open-source distance query library

Tags: ros, collision

[image: Rosanswers logo]

is there a geometric distance query library that is under an open source license preferably under LGPL, BSD, or Apache?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9762/open-source-distance-query-library/) by [Rosen Diankov](https://answers.ros.org/users/104/rosen-diankov/) on ROS Answers with karma: 516 on 2011-04-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know about this one, but have not tried anything:
[PQP](http://gamma.cs.unc.edu/SSV/)

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know whether it's ready for use, but maybe [FCL](http://ros.org/wiki/fcl_ros) can do what you need.

---

Originally posted by [Brian Gerkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/8/brian-gerkey/) with karma: 2916 on 2011-12-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rosen Diankov](https://answers.ros.org/users/104/rosen-diankov/) on 2011-12-06**:
FCL looks exciting! thanks for the tip